# Async calls chaining in Metro app

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, microsoft-metro, async-await

I am quite new to Metro dev and I only hope I will be able to express my question in an understandable way...

Actually I am porting a part of my old application to Metro. The logic part is a separated project (Portable Library) and it should serve to 1) the old WPF app and 2) the new Metro app. The basic logic is the same but some subsystems (for example file operations manager) must be coded differently - i.e. async way for Metro.

My question is: Do I have to rewrite the whole chain of methods caller-callee to the new async paradigm? Let's say I have a chain of 4 methods, starting by method A = Metro UI event async handler (it makes sense to me to code it as async void as it is the top fire&forget event), through the next 2 methods (B and C) placed in different layers of my application, down to the method D containing "await CreateFileAsync" method (made async by Microsoft).

Now: async CreateFileAsync method should be called with await. That forces me to make method D async too. To call method D from C and C from B and B from A - do I have to rewrite all A, B and C into the async-await style?

I can feel I am missing a deeper knowledge so I am trying to educate myself but concurrently I wanted to try my luck here...

Do I have to rewrite a big part of my code? Is any of my statements above wrong?

Many thanks in advance, Hans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you do rewrite your portable library to be asynchronous. It's not as bad as it used to be; Microsoft worked very hard on `async`/`await` to make it as easy as possible to convert synchronous code to asynchronous. I expect that a whole lot of others will be doing the same in the near future, and R# will probably implement a "make async" rewriting.

There are non-obvious pitfalls when mixing synchronous and asynchronous code - see Stephen Toub's last blog post [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) For this reason, I think it's just cleaner to expose asynchronous operations as asynchronous APIs (and synchronous operations as synchronous APIs).

**Update:** If you do want synchronous code to call asynchronous code, then you can use the `Task.WaitAndUnwrapException` extension method in [my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com). However, you still have the problems mentioned in Stephen Toub's post, namely these:

1. You can deadlock if your library doesn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere it can.
2. You can also deadlock if you run into the maximum number of threads in the thread pool.

(2) is not that common anymore, but (1) is a real possibility. It's regularly [brought up](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/async/thread/269172a3-adb9-4b5e-9ac1-8b67ff920177#48b596cc-5eca-4d0e-8743-10d59b64e2ce) by people who are just testing out `async` so they mix it with synchronous code.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your answer. I read that article couple of hours ago but will do once again with fresh eyes. The problem is that it is quite a LOT OF code. Originally I implemented MVC pattern (did not know MVVM that time) which gave me for example quite a lot of one-or-two-liner methods in the Controller. Do I have to rewrite all of them? If I can decide not to... how would I call my async D method from my synchronous C method?

Comment: And if I decide to rewrite all... In another article (http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) I found that for such one-liners Task.FromResult should be preferred to classic await. Do you agree with that article in this point?

Comment: @Hans - he wrote that article, so I would certainly hope so :)

Comment: Stephen - the Task.FromResult in that Feb blog post Hans linked to seems confusing to me - you could only use it if you already have the result (of course), so why would such a method even return Task<TResult> instead of TResult?  I could see it if you determine you already have the precomputed value (for instance, from an in-memory cache) and need to keep Task<TResult> as the response for the 'cache miss' case, but that doens't seem to be what the blog post is referring to - can you elaborate with an example method?

Comment: @James: The cache is a good example. Other times a method can just do a quick check and return a constant, saving the real `async` implementation for the complex cases (e.g., the [fast path `Database.MoveNextAsync` example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx)). Or if it's just doing a bit of (synchronous) pre-processing before a single call to another `async` method. Or if you're overriding `Task<TResult>` methods from a base class but have a synchronous implementation. I'll clarify the blog post.

Comment: @James - how funny, I surely haven't noticed ;)

Comment: @Hans: See my updated answer re synchronously waiting for asynchronous operations.

Comment: @StephenCleary Considering pros and cons I agree with your advice and I will rewrite the whole method chain. However I am still confused about your blog advice recommendation of Task.FromResult. As I said many of my methods in portable library are simple, so they sound as CANDIDATES for Task.FromResult. Performance should be better.. but I am worried about readability of the code (hard to recognize on the first spot the nature of the method). Are such methods truly async? I do not already have the result as James comments - so from this perspective my methods ARE NOT CANDIDATES. Which way?

Comment: ... must add that many of the simple methods I mentioned above are void in their sync form, so Simple Task in async, meaning I do not need the result on place for this kind of methods.

Comment: My blog recommends that you make the methods synchronous *if possible*. If you don't already have the result, you can't use `Task.FromResult`. Some APIs have several public "entry point" methods that just supply different arguments to a single private "core" method; in that case it may be possible to make the "core" `async` and just have each "entry point" return the task directly from the "core". I wouldn't worry about readability - the method does return `Task`, even though it's not `async`.

Comment: Regarding "are such methods truly async?" - it really depends on what you call "truly async", and whether you're making a distinction between the *method* being async and the *return type* (or *value*) being async.

Comment: Just one more comment: if in doubt, just make them all `async`. It'll still work fine, just be slightly less efficient.

Comment: As indicated in my "... must add" comment above I started using Task.FromResult approach on simple Task methods, await approach on more complicated Task methods and all Task<T> methods. All seems to be working. Thank you once again.