# Calling async function in sync method in PCL in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have this function:

```
public async Task<string> GetData() 
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "My Link Here...");
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    string value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
    return value;
}
```

It gets the data from a webapi, and then I have to use that data to build a chart in Xamarin Forms using Steema Teechart. The problem is that I can't call the function GetData() in the class where I build the chart, because the method in which I want to use the data isn't async. How Am I supposed to call GetData() and use the string?

I have tried:

```
Task<string> s = GetData ();
s.Wait ();
string initialValues = s.Result;
```

But it stops my app and crashes it after a while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [async Task is freezing the UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592957/async-task-is-freezing-the-ui)

Comment: you can use the AsyncEx library, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183179/async-calls-chaining-in-metro-app the extension method is called `WaitAndUnwrapException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I can't call the function GetData() in the class where I build the chart, because the method in which I want to use the data isn't async. How Am I supposed to call GetData() and use the string?

You make the calling method `async` and then use `await`:

```
string initialValues = await GetData();
```

Yes, this means that your calling method also needs to return a `Task`/`Task<T>`, which means that *its* calling methods should also be `async`, etc. This "growth" of `async` is perfectly natural.

Comment: Yes, but the method in which I want to use the data returns a model which I have to use to build the chart, and async methods should be void or return some kind of task, which doesn't work for me..

Comment: @IliaStoilov: Then your return type should be `Task<MyModelType>`.